What's the chance of getting at least a single 1 on a 64 sided die thrown 64 times?
What's the chance of getting at least a single 1 on a 64 sided die thrown 64 times?
I believe we can calculate that by multiplying the chances of not rolling a 1 in each of the 64 throws, which would be $(\frac{63}{64})^{64}$, then $(1 - 0.36)$ or so gives us approximately a 63% chance of rolling at least a single 1, but logically speaking, shouldn't we anticipate seeing each number roughly once on average if the die is fair?

Knowing that the expected number of times you see the $1$ is $1$ tells you little about the actual probability.  Your calculation is the way to go.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Short answer: your approach of asking what is the probability of not getting a 64 and then using the complement was correct.
So $P(\text{64 at least once})=1-P(\text{no 64s})=1-(\frac{63}{64})^{64}\approx 0.635$
Which is closer to 64% than 63% but your logic remains valid.

Expected value is a long run average, not a specific statement that something will happen.

But there is an expected number of numbers that will be seen once (not sure how to practically compute it though)
